# Effective way to display different contents in the same style of accordion in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

what is an effective way to display different contents in the multiple accordions?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nplwc.png)
This is what I am doing in my project, and obviously shipping information and delivery options would contain different textboxs, labels, and input boxes.

As of now, I am hardcoding every label, input box, textbox for the different accordions, but I don't think this is very smart and effective. Hardcoing makes my code very long for this one page. Below is a snippet of how I am hardcoding everything.
Or should I simply divide the different accordions into different react classes to make the code shorter.

```
<div className="dropdown-header" onClick={toggle}>
                                <h4 className="dropdown-text">Shipping Information</h4>
                                <span className="dropdown-selection">{selected ? '-' : '+'}</span>
                            </div>
                            {selected && (<div className="wrapper">
                                <div className="row">
                                    <div className="col-md-6">
                                        <div className="info-group mb-3">
                                            <label>First name</label>
                                            <input type="text" className="info-input" name="firstname" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="col-md-6">
                                        <div className="info-group mb-3">
                                            <label>Last name</label>
                                            <input type="text" className="info-input" name="firstname" />
                                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make everything that's going to be re-used into a component itself and pass through parameters you want to be different.

Please see: https://react.dev/learn/your-first-component

For Example:

```
export function AccordionExample({heading, label1, label2}) {
 return (
  <div className="dropdown-header" onClick={toggle}>
    <h4 className="dropdown-text">{heading}</h4>
    <span className="dropdown-selection">{selected ? '-' : '+'}</span>
  </div>
  {selected && (<div className="wrapper">
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-6">
        <div className="info-group mb-3">
          <label>{label1}</label>
          <input type="text" className="info-input" name="firstname" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="col-md-6">
        <div className="info-group mb-3">
          <label>{label2}</label>
          <input type="text" className="info-input" name="lastname" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  } 
  );
}
```

You would then call your component where needed like so:

```
<AccordionExample heading="Shipping Information" label1="First Name" label2="Last Name" />
<AccordionExample heading="Delivery Option" label1="Option One" label2="Option Two" />
```